# Why is $f(x+h) = 3x+3h-1$ when $f(x)=3x-1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$f(x+h) = 3x+3h-1$ when $f(x)=3x-1$

Is there some kind of factoring that gets you $3x+3h-1$? It looks the 3h comes out of nowhere.

Comment: What do you get when you replace $x$ by $x+h$ in $f(x)=3x-1$?

Comment: $f(x+h)=3(x+h)-1$

Comment: $f(x+h)$???????

Comment: Okay. I get it now. I got this from a video and the guy in the video didn't do the factoring. I don't like it when calculus teachers skip the factoring. So esoteric and elitist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
f(x) = 3x - 1 \implies f(x+h) = 3(x+h) - 1 = 3x + 3h - 1
$$